# Is it possible to add links in options in amp?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

```
<select class="nav-slect show-nav">
    <option class="" value="index">Home Page</option>
    <option class="dasm" value="dasm">Courses - DASM</option>
    <option class="dcct" value="dcct">Courses - DCCT</option>
    <option class="datm" value="datm">Courses - DATM</option>
    <option class="dhotm" value="dhotm">Courses - DHOTM</option>
    <option class="galileo" value="galileo-training">Galileo Training</option>
    <option class="first" value="first-aid-training">Firts-Aid Training</option>
    <option class="swim" value="swimming-certification">Swimming Certification</option>
    <option class="gal" value="gallery">Gallery</option>
    <option class="gal" value="thailand-immersion-program">Thailand Immersion</option>
    <option class="high" value="placements-highlights">Highlights</option>
    <option class="testi" value="placements-testimonials">Testimonials</option>
    <option class="livefeed" value="live-feed">Live Feed</option>
    <option class="ourstory" value="our-story">Our Story</option>
    <option class="miss" value="mission-vision">Mission &amp; Vision</option>
    <option class="faqq" value="faq">FAQ</option>
    <option class="contactus" value="contact-us">Contact Us</option>
    <option class="blog" value="https://www.aptadvantage.com/blog">Blog</option>
    <option class="knowmore" value="know-more" style="font-weight:600;color:#0e54ab;">Know More</option>
</select>
```

This is how the select box contains and I need to add links in options.I tried using on tap events but couldn't find anything fruitful. 
fleapo.in/apt is the website on which I am working, the select option can be seen in the mobile version.

Comment: Hi Javed could you please explain your requirement in detail? Do you just want to redirect to those pages on clicking the option?

Comment: Yes, for example if someone clicks on dasm then it should be redirected to stackoverflow.com for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work in AMP but work around is to use accordion or use AMP Bind.
Please see in snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.tele2.lv/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Vadošais mobilo sakaru operators Latvijā | Tele2</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="description" content="Jaunākie mobilie telefoni, izdevīgi mobilo sakaru pakalpojumi, 4G internets 97% Latvijas iedzīvotāju. Pievienoties  visērtāk tele2.lv!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="tele2, tele 2, telefoni, mobilie sakari, 4G internets, MBB internets, balss tarifi">
  <script async="" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style amp-boilerplate="">body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate="">body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

  <style amp-custom="">/*! Bassplate | MIT License | http://github.com/basscss/bassplate */
/*! normalize.css v5.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */  
html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;box-sizing:border-box;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}article,aside,footer,header,nav,section{display:block}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}figcaption,figure,main{display:block}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}pre{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:inherit;font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background-color:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}audio,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;line-height:1.15;margin:0}button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=reset],[type=submit],button,html [type=button]{-webkit-appearance:button}[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}[type=button]:-moz-focusring,[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,button:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{box-sizing:border-box;color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}progress{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}textarea{overflow:auto}[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}details,menu{display:block}summary{display:list-item}canvas{display:inline-block}[hidden],template{display:none}.h1{font-size:2rem}.h2{font-size:2rem}.h3{font-size:1.5rem}.h4{font-size:1.125rem}.h5{font-size:.875rem}.h6{font-size:.75rem}.font-family-inherit{font-family:inherit}.font-size-inherit{font-size:inherit}.text-decoration-none{text-decoration:none}.bold{font-weight:700}.regular{font-weight:400}.italic{font-style:italic}.caps{text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.2em}.left-align{text-align:left}.center{text-align:center}.right-align{text-align:right}.justify{text-align:justify}.nowrap{white-space:nowrap}.break-word{word-wrap:break-word}.line-height-1{line-height:1rem}.line-height-2{line-height:1.125rem}.line-height-3{line-height:1.5rem}.line-height-4{line-height:2rem}.list-style-none{list-style:none}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.truncate{max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.list-reset{list-style:none;padding-left:0}.inline{display:inline}.block{display:block}.inline-block{display:inline-block}.table{display:table}.table-cell{display:table-cell}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.overflow-scroll{overflow:scroll}.overflow-auto{overflow:auto}.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.left{float:left}.right{float:right}.fit{max-width:100%}.max-width-1{max-width:24rem}.max-width-2{max-width:32rem}.max-width-3{max-width:48rem}.max-width-4{max-width:64rem}.border-box{box-sizing:border-box}.align-baseline{vertical-align:baseline}.align-top{vertical-align:top}.align-middle{vertical-align:middle}.align-bottom{vertical-align:bottom}.m0{margin:0}.mt0{margin-top:0}.mr0{margin-right:0}.mb0{margin-bottom:0}.ml0,.mx0{margin-left:0}.mx0{margin-right:0}.my0{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}.m1{margin:.5rem}.mt1{margin-top:.5rem}.mr1{margin-right:.5rem}.mb1{margin-bottom:.5rem}.ml1,.mx1{margin-left:.5rem}.mx1{margin-right:.5rem}.my1{margin-top:.5rem;margin-bottom:.5rem}.m2{margin:1rem}.mt2{margin-top:1rem}.mr2{margin-right:1rem}.mb2{margin-bottom:1rem}.ml2,.mx2{margin-left:1rem}.mx2{margin-right:1rem}.my2{margin-top:1rem;margin-bottom:1rem}.m3{margin:1.5rem}.mt3{margin-top:1.5rem}.mr3{margin-right:1.5rem}.mb3{margin-bottom:1.5rem}.ml3,.mx3{margin-left:1.5rem}.mx3{margin-right:1.5rem}.my3{margin-top:1.5rem;margin-bottom:1.5rem}.m4{margin:2rem}.mt4{margin-top:2rem}.mr4{margin-right:2rem}.mb4{margin-bottom:2rem}.ml4,.mx4{margin-left:2rem}.mx4{margin-right:2rem}.my4{margin-top:2rem;margin-bottom:2rem}.mxn1{margin-left:-.5rem;margin-right:-.5rem}.mxn2{margin-left:-1rem;margin-right:-1rem}.mxn3{margin-left:-1.5rem;margin-right:-1.5rem}.mxn4{margin-left:-2rem;margin-right:-2rem}.ml-auto{margin-left:auto}.mr-auto,.mx-auto{margin-right:auto}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto}.p0{padding:0}.pt0{padding-top:0}.pr0{padding-right:0}.pb0{padding-bottom:0}.pl0,.px0{padding-left:0}.px0{padding-right:0}.py0{padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0}.p1{padding:.5rem}.pt1{padding-top:.5rem}.pr1{padding-right:.5rem}.pb1{padding-bottom:.5rem}.pl1{padding-left:.5rem}.py1{padding-top:.5rem;padding-bottom:.5rem}.px1{padding-left:.5rem;padding-right:.5rem}.p2{padding:10px}.pt2{padding-top:1rem}.pr2{padding-right:1rem}.pb2{padding-bottom:1rem}.pl2{padding-left:1rem}.py2{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px2{padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem}.p3{padding:1.5rem}.pt3{padding-top:1.5rem}.pr3{padding-right:1.5rem}.pb3{padding-bottom:1.5rem}.pl3{padding-left:1.5rem}.py3{padding-top:1.5rem;padding-bottom:1.5rem}.px3{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.p4{padding:2rem}.pt4{padding-top:2rem}.pr4{padding-right:2rem}.pb4{padding-bottom:2rem}.pl4{padding-left:2rem}.py4{padding-top:2rem;padding-bottom:2rem}.px4{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}.col{float:left}.col,.col-right{box-sizing:border-box}.col-right{float:right}.col-1{width:8.33333%}.col-2{width:16.66667%}.col-3{width:25%}.col-4{width:33.33333%}.col-5{width:41.66667%}.col-6{width:50%}.col-7{width:58.33333%}.col-8{width:66.66667%}.col-9{width:75%}.col-10{width:83.33333%}.col-11{width:91.66667%}.col-12{width:100%}@media (min-width:40.06rem){.sm-col{float:left;box-sizing:border-box}.sm-col-right{float:right;box-sizing:border-box}.sm-col-1{width:8.33333%}.sm-col-2{width:16.66667%}.sm-col-3{width:25%}.sm-col-4{width:33.33333%}.sm-col-5{width:41.66667%}.sm-col-6{width:50%}.sm-col-7{width:58.33333%}.sm-col-8{width:66.66667%}.sm-col-9{width:75%}.sm-col-10{width:83.33333%}.sm-col-11{width:91.66667%}.sm-col-12{width:100%}}@media (min-width:52.06rem){.md-col{float:left;box-sizing:border-box}.md-col-right{float:right;box-sizing:border-box}.md-col-1{width:8.33333%}.md-col-2{width:16.66667%}.md-col-3{width:25%}.md-col-4{width:33.33333%}.md-col-5{width:41.66667%}.md-col-6{width:50%}.md-col-7{width:58.33333%}.md-col-8{width:66.66667%}.md-col-9{width:75%}.md-col-10{width:83.33333%}.md-col-11{width:91.66667%}.md-col-12{width:100%}}@media (min-width:64.06rem){.lg-col{float:left;box-sizing:border-box}.lg-col-right{float:right;box-sizing:border-box}.lg-col-1{width:8.33333%}.lg-col-2{width:16.66667%}.lg-col-3{width:25%}.lg-col-4{width:33.33333%}.lg-col-5{width:41.66667%}.lg-col-6{width:50%}.lg-col-7{width:58.33333%}.lg-col-8{width:66.66667%}.lg-col-9{width:75%}.lg-col-10{width:83.33333%}.lg-col-11{width:91.66667%}.lg-col-12{width:100%}}.flex{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}@media (min-width:40.06rem){.sm-flex{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}}@media (min-width:52.06rem){.md-flex{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}}@media (min-width:64.06rem){.lg-flex{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}}.flex-column{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.flex-wrap{-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap}.items-start{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start}.items-end{-webkit-box-align:end;-ms-flex-align:end;align-items:flex-end}.items-center{-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.items-baseline{-webkit-box-align:baseline;-ms-flex-align:baseline;align-items:baseline}.items-stretch{-webkit-box-align:stretch;-ms-flex-align:stretch;align-items:stretch}.self-start{-ms-flex-item-align:start;align-self:flex-start}.self-end{-ms-flex-item-align:end;align-self:flex-end}.self-center{-ms-flex-item-align:center;-ms-grid-row-align:center;align-self:center}.self-baseline{-ms-flex-item-align:baseline;align-self:baseline}.self-stretch{-ms-flex-item-align:stretch;-ms-grid-row-align:stretch;align-self:stretch}.justify-start{-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start}.justify-end{-webkit-box-pack:end;-ms-flex-pack:end;justify-content:flex-end}.justify-center{-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center}.justify-between{-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.justify-around{-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.content-start{-ms-flex-line-pack:start;align-content:flex-start}.content-end{-ms-flex-line-pack:end;align-content:flex-end}.content-center{-ms-flex-line-pack:center;align-content:center}.content-between{-ms-flex-line-pack:justify;align-content:space-between}.content-around{-ms-flex-line-pack:distribute;align-content:space-around}.content-stretch{-ms-flex-line-pack:stretch;align-content:stretch}.flex-auto{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1 1 auto;flex:1 1 auto;min-width:0;min-height:0}.flex-none{-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:none;flex:none}.order-0{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:1;-ms-flex-order:0;order:0}.order-1{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;-ms-flex-order:1;order:1}.order-2{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:3;-ms-flex-order:2;order:2}.order-3{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:4;-ms-flex-order:3;order:3}.order-last{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:100000;-ms-flex-order:99999;order:99999}.relative{position:relative}.absolute{position:absolute}.fixed{position:fixed}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.bottom-0{bottom:0}.left-0{left:0}.z1{z-index:1}.z2{z-index:2}.z3{z-index:3}.z4{z-index:4}.border{border-style:solid;border-width:1px}.border-top{border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1px}.border-right{border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px}.border-bottom{border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px}.border-left{border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1px}.border-none{border:0}.rounded{border-radius:3px}.circle{border-radius:50%}.rounded-top{border-radius:3px 3px 0 0}.rounded-right{border-radius:0 3px 3px 0}.rounded-bottom{border-radius:0 0 3px 3px}.rounded-left{border-radius:3px 0 0 3px}.not-rounded{border-radius:0}.hide{position:absolute;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px)}@media (max-width:40rem){.xs-hide{display:none}}@media (min-width:40.06rem) and (max-width:52rem){.sm-hide{display:none}}@media (min-width:52.06rem) and (max-width:64rem){.md-hide{display:none}}@media (min-width:64.06rem){.lg-hide{display:none}}.display-none{display:none}*{box-sizing:border-box}main{max-width:700px;margin:0 auto}p{padding:0;margin:0}.ampstart-accent{color:#003f93}#content:target{margin-top:calc(0px - 3.5rem);padding-top:3.5rem}.ampstart-title-lg{font-size:3rem;line-height:3.5rem;letter-spacing:.06rem}.ampstart-title-md{font-size:2rem;line-height:2.5rem;letter-spacing:.06rem}.ampstart-title-sm{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:2rem;letter-spacing:.06rem}.ampstart-subtitle{line-height:1.5rem;letter-spacing:normal}.ampstart-subtitle{color:#003f93;font-size:1rem}.ampstart-byline,.ampstart-caption,.ampstart-hint,.ampstart-label{font-size:.875rem;color:#4f4f4f;line-height:1.125rem;letter-spacing:.06rem}.ampstart-label{text-transform:uppercase}.ampstart-footer,.ampstart-small-text{font-size:.75rem;line-height:1rem;letter-spacing:.06rem}.ampstart-card{box-shadow:0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12)}.h1,h1{font-size:2rem;line-height:1}.h2,h2{font-size:2rem;line-height:1.2}.h3,h3{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:1.2}.h4,h4{font-size:1.125rem;line-height:1.2}.h5,h5{font-size:.875rem;line-height:1.125}.h6,h6{font-size:.75rem;line-height:1}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:0;padding:0;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:.06rem}a,a:active,a:visited{color:inherit}.ampstart-btn{font-family:inherit;font-weight:inherit;font-size:1rem;line-height:1.125rem;padding:.7em .8em;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px solid #fff}.ampstart-btn:visited{color:#fff}.ampstart-btn-secondary{background-color:#fff;color:#000;border:1px solid #000}.ampstart-btn-secondary:visited{color:#000}.ampstart-btn:active .ampstart-btn:focus{opacity:.8}.ampstart-btn[disabled],.ampstart-btn[disabled]:active,.ampstart-btn[disabled]:focus,.ampstart-btn[disabled]:hover{opacity:.5;outline:0;cursor:default}.ampstart-dropcap:first-letter{color:#000;font-size:3rem;font-weight:700;float:left;overflow:hidden;line-height:3rem;margin-left:0;margin-right:.5rem}.ampstart-initialcap{padding-top:1rem;margin-top:1.5rem}.ampstart-initialcap:first-letter{color:#000;font-size:3rem;font-weight:700;margin-left:-2px}.ampstart-pullquote{border:none;border-left:4px solid #000;font-size:1.5rem;padding-left:1.5rem}.ampstart-byline time{font-style:normal;white-space:nowrap}.amp-carousel-button-next{background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 34 34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Next</title><path d="M25.557 14.7L13.818 2.961 16.8 0l16.8 16.8-16.8 16.8-2.961-2.961L25.557 18.9H0v-4.2z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>')}.amp-carousel-button-prev{background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 34 34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Previous</title><path d="M33.6 14.7H8.043L19.782 2.961 16.8 0 0 16.8l16.8 16.8 2.961-2.961L8.043 18.9H33.6z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>')}.ampstart-dropdown{min-width:200px}.ampstart-dropdown.absolute{z-index:100}.ampstart-dropdown.absolute>section,.ampstart-dropdown.absolute>section>header{height:100%}.ampstart-dropdown>section>header{background-color:#000;border:0;color:#fff}.absolute .ampstart-dropdown-items{z-index:200}.ampstart-dropdown-item{background-color:#000;color:#003f93;opacity:.9}.ampstart-dropdown-item:active,.ampstart-dropdown-item:hover{opacity:1}.ampstart-footer{background-color:#fff;color:#000;padding-top:5rem;padding-bottom:5rem}.ampstart-footer .ampstart-icon{fill:#000}.ampstart-footer .ampstart-social-follow li:last-child{margin-right:0}.ampstart-image-fullpage-hero{color:#fff}.ampstart-fullpage-hero-heading-text,.ampstart-image-fullpage-hero .ampstart-image-credit{-webkit-box-decoration-break:clone;box-decoration-break:clone;background:#000;padding:0 1rem .2rem}.ampstart-image-fullpage-hero>amp-img{max-height:calc(100vh - 3.5rem)}.ampstart-image-fullpage-hero>amp-img img{-o-object-fit:cover;object-fit:cover}.ampstart-fullpage-hero-heading{line-height:3.5rem}.ampstart-fullpage-hero-cta{background:transparent}.ampstart-readmore{background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.65),transparent);background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0,transparent);color:#fff;margin-top:5rem;padding-bottom:3.5rem}.ampstart-readmore:after{display:block;content:"⌄";font-size:2rem}.ampstart-readmore-text{background:#000}@media (min-width:52.06rem){.ampstart-image-fullpage-hero>amp-img{height:60vh}}.ampstart-image-heading{color:#fff;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.65),transparent);background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0,transparent)}.ampstart-image-heading>*{margin:0}amp-carousel .ampstart-image-with-heading{margin-bottom:0}.ampstart-image-with-caption figcaption{color:#4f4f4f;line-height:1.125rem}amp-carousel .ampstart-image-with-caption{margin-bottom:0}.ampstart-input{max-width:100%;width:300px;min-width:100px;font-size:1rem;line-height:1.5rem}.ampstart-input [disabled],.ampstart-input [disabled]+label{opacity:.5}.ampstart-input [disabled]:focus{outline:0}.ampstart-input>input,.ampstart-input>select,.ampstart-input>textarea{width:100%;margin-top:1rem;line-height:1.5rem;border:0;border-radius:0;border-bottom:1px solid #4a4a4a;background:none;color:#4a4a4a;outline:0}.ampstart-input>label{color:#003f93;pointer-events:none;text-align:left;font-size:.875rem;line-height:1rem;opacity:0;-webkit-animation:.2s;animation:.2s;-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards}.ampstart-input>input:focus,.ampstart-input>select:focus,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus{outline:0}.ampstart-input>input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,.ampstart-input>select:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input:focus::-moz-placeholder,.ampstart-input>select:focus::-moz-placeholder,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder{color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,.ampstart-input>select:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input:focus::placeholder,.ampstart-input>select:focus::placeholder,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus::placeholder{color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input:not(:placeholder-shown):not([disabled])+label,.ampstart-input>select:not(:placeholder-shown):not([disabled])+label,.ampstart-input>textarea:not(:placeholder-shown):not([disabled])+label{opacity:1}.ampstart-input>input:focus+label,.ampstart-input>select:focus+label,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus+label{-webkit-animation-name:a;animation-name:a}@-webkit-keyframes a{to{opacity:1}}@keyframes a{to{opacity:1}}.ampstart-input>label:after{content:"";height:2px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:45%;background:#003f93;-webkit-transition:.2s;transition:.2s;-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);visibility:hidden;width:10px}.ampstart-input>input:focus+label:after,.ampstart-input>select:focus+label:after,.ampstart-input>textarea:focus+label:after{left:0;width:100%;visibility:visible}.ampstart-input>input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none}.ampstart-input>input[type=range]{border-bottom:0}.ampstart-input>input[type=range]+label:after{display:none}.ampstart-input>select{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none}.ampstart-input>select+label:before{content:"⌄";line-height:1.5rem;position:absolute;right:5px;zoom:2;top:0;bottom:0;color:#003f93}.ampstart-input-chk,.ampstart-input-radio{width:auto;color:#4a4a4a}.ampstart-input input[type=checkbox],.ampstart-input input[type=radio]{margin-top:0;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #003f93;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:.5rem;text-align:center}.ampstart-input input[type=radio]{border-radius:20px}.ampstart-input input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled])+label,.ampstart-input input[type=radio]:not([disabled])+label{pointer-events:auto;-webkit-animation:none;animation:none;vertical-align:middle;opacity:1;cursor:pointer}.ampstart-input input[type=checkbox]+label:after,.ampstart-input input[type=radio]+label:after{display:none}.ampstart-input input[type=checkbox]:after,.ampstart-input input[type=radio]:after{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;content:" ";line-height:1.4rem;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;background-color:#fff}.ampstart-input input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{background-color:#003f93;color:#fff;content:"✓"}.ampstart-input input[type=radio]:checked{background-color:#fff}.ampstart-input input[type=radio]:after{top:3px;bottom:3px;left:3px;right:3px;border-radius:12px}.ampstart-input input[type=radio]:checked:after{content:"";font-size:3rem;background-color:#003f93}.ampstart-input>label,_:-ms-lang(x){opacity:1}.ampstart-input>input:-ms-input-placeholder,_:-ms-lang(x){color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input::placeholder,_:-ms-lang(x){color:transparent}.ampstart-input>input::-ms-input-placeholder,_:-ms-lang(x){color:transparent}.ampstart-input>select::-ms-expand{display:none}.ampstart-headerbar{background-color:#fff;color:#000;z-index:999;box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.ampstart-headerbar-nav .ampstart-nav-item{padding:0 1rem;background:transparent;opacity:.8}.ampstart-headerbar-nav{line-height:3.5rem}.ampstart-nav-item:active,.ampstart-nav-item:focus,.ampstart-nav-item:hover{opacity:1}.ampstart-navbar-trigger:focus{outline:none}.ampstart-nav a,.ampstart-navbar-trigger,.ampstart-sidebar-faq a{cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none}.ampstart-nav .ampstart-label{color:inherit}.ampstart-navbar-trigger{line-height:3.5rem;font-size:2rem}.ampstart-headerbar-nav{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1}.ampstart-nav-search{-webkit-box-flex:0.5;-ms-flex-positive:0.5;flex-grow:0.5}.ampstart-headerbar .ampstart-nav-search:active,.ampstart-headerbar .ampstart-nav-search:focus,.ampstart-headerbar .ampstart-nav-search:hover{box-shadow:none}.ampstart-nav-search>input{border:none;border-radius:3px;line-height:normal}.ampstart-nav-dropdown{min-width:200px}.ampstart-nav-dropdown amp-accordion header{background-color:#fff;border:none}.ampstart-nav-dropdown amp-accordion ul{background-color:#fff}.ampstart-nav-dropdown .ampstart-dropdown-item,.ampstart-nav-dropdown .ampstart-dropdown>section>header{background-color:#fff;color:#2aaee4}.ampstart-nav-dropdown .ampstart-dropdown-item{color:#003f93}.ampstart-sidebar{background-color:#fff;color:#000;min-width:300px;width:300px}.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-icon{fill:#003f93}.ampstart-sidebar-header{line-height:3.5rem;min-height:3.5rem}.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-dropdown-item,.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-dropdown header,.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-faq-item,.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-nav-item,.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-social-follow{margin:0 0 2rem}.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-nav-dropdown{margin:0}.ampstart-sidebar .ampstart-navbar-trigger{line-height:inherit}.ampstart-navbar-trigger svg{pointer-events:none}
.color-inherit{color:inherit}.border-thick{border-width:3px}.border-darken{border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.0625)}.border-gray{border-color:#ccc}.black{color:#111}.white{color:#fff}.blue{color:#07c}.gray{color:#ccc}.darken{color:rgba(0,0,0,.0625)}.bg-black{background-color:#000}.bg-white{background-color:#fff}.bg-blue{background-color:#07c}.bg-gray{background-color:#ccc}.bg-darken{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.0625)}

.ls0{letter-spacing:0}.fw700{font-weight:700;}.fw900{font-weight: 900;}.lh1{line-height: .85;}.fs40{font-size: 40px;}.lh11{line-height: 1}
body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; color: #777;letter-spacing: 0px;}
.acc1{width: 80%;}.acc2{width: 20%;}.cc1{    color: #e6007e;}
.fistacc section header{background: #000;border:none;padding: 12px 20px 14.5px 20px;font-size: 12px;line-height: 1;font-weight: 700;outline: none;}
.fistacc i{position: absolute;right: 10px;color: #999;}
.fistacc section.acc2 header{padding-left: 10px;}.pc20{padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;}
.fistacc section ul{
    color: #000;z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.22);
} 
.fs26{font-size: 26px;}.fs24{font-size: 24px}.fs36{font-size: 36px}.lh115{line-height: 1.15}.fs20{font-size: 20px;}
.fistacc section ul li{padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px; font-size: 14px;}.cc999{color: #999;}  
.fistacc section[expanded] ul li:hover {background: #009fdf42;}   
.fistacc section.acc2 ul li{ padding:0px 10px;} 
.fistacc section[expanded] header{outline: none;}


  
</style>
</head>
<body class="m0 p0">
  <amp-user-notification id="my-notification" layout="nodisplay">
    <div>
      This is an amp-user-notification. It uses a backend service to verify if the notification has to be shown.
      <button on="tap:my-notification.dismiss" class="show">I accept</button>
    </div>
  </amp-user-notification>
  <header class="ampstart-headerbar clearfix">
    <amp-accordion expand-single-section disable-session-states class="relative fistacc white">
      <section class="acc1 inline-block absolute">
        <header>Privātpersonām <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></header>
        <ul class="list-reset">
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/">Privātpersonām</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/biznesam/">Biznesam</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/tele2/tele2-jaunumi/">Par Tele2</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/karjera/">Darbs Tele2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section class="acc2 inline-block absolute right-0">
        <header>LAT <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></header>
        <ul class="list-reset">
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/">LAT</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.tele2.lv/ru/">RUS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
    
  </header>
  

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajeet for your reply and the code.
But this won't work for me.